# How to make a react table whose rows and columns come from a JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs

I am attempting to build a dynamic table using React that is based on the JSON format:

```
[{ "name": "Video1", "text": "video 1 text"},
   "name": "Video2", "text": "video 2 text",
   "name": "Video3", "text": "video 3 text",...}]
```

I need it to be dynamic as there will be a continuous adding to the JSON and I want the table to update automatically.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Hi Edele, welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you already tried anything yourself? For example, you can easily use a `for` loop or `.map` to iterate over the json results and create output.

Comment: I'm  pretty new to React so I tried a for loop and it didnt work. I'll try .map next, thank you

Comment: Hi Edele, no worries. We all have to start at some point. Devserkan gave a nice answer with a good example. That should help you along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to provide what have you tried up to now and where you got stuck. In SO, if you don't provide that information your question probably will be closed. But, here is a welcome present: You can use JS expressions in JSX, how good. So, as @Roy Scheffers suggested you can use map to do create tables or anything you want.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Video1", text: "video 1 text" },
  { name: "Video2", text: "video 2 text" },
  { name: "Video3", text: "video 3 text" },
];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <table>
      {data.map(el => (
        <tr>
          <td>{el.name}</td>
          <td>{el.text}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This example is just for fun:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { name: "Video1", text: "video 1 text" },
      { name: "Video2", text: "video 2 text" },
      { name: "Video3", text: "video 3 text" },
    ],
    count: 1,
  };

  updateTable = () => { 
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      data: [...prevState.data, { name: `foo${prevState.count}`, text: `bar${prevState.count}` }],
      count: prevState.count += 1,
    }))
    if (this.state.data.length > 5) { clearInterval(this.intervalId); }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.updateTable, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          {this.state.data.map(el => (
            <tr>
              <td>{el.name}</td>
              <td>{el.text}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped so much. Got the table up and working.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great React npm projects out there as well that can do this for you and give you a lot of flexibility. I found this one https://github.com/agracio/ts-react-json-table and it looks really cool. I haven't used it just yet, but I am about to, as I was searching for something to take JSON and make a table quickly.